# How do I get the variables I set in the if statements to carry over to the rest of my code?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TripCost 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String destination;
    String hotel;
    int days = 3;
    double mealCost;
    double regularMeal = 31.00;
    double highCostMeal = 52.00;
    double gasPrice = 3.29;
    double miles;
    double airfare;
    double hotelCost;
    double budgetel = 76.00;
    double holidayInn = 109.00;
    double sheraton = 138.00;
    double hyatt = 215.00;

    System.out.println("Here are the places you may go for vacation:");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" 1. Niagra Falls");
    System.out.println(" 2. Chicago");
    System.out.println(" 3. San Francisco");
    System.out.println(" 4. Las Vegas");
    System.out.println(" 5. St. Louis");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Please select the number of the destination: ");
    int destinationChoice = keyboard.nextInt();


    if (destinationChoice == 1)
    {
        miles = 257.00;
        airfare = 0;
        mealCost = regularMeal;
        destination = "Niagra Falls"; 
    }
    else if (destinationChoice == 2)
    {
        miles = 303.00;
        airfare = 0;
        mealCost = highCostMeal;
        destination = "Chicago";
    }
    else if (destinationChoice == 3)
    {
        miles = 0;
        airfare = 630.00;
        mealCost = highCostMeal;
        destination = "San Francisco";
    }
    else if (destinationChoice == 4)
    {
        miles = 0;
        airfare = 415.00;
        mealCost = highCostMeal;
        destination = "Las Vegas";
    }
    else if (destinationChoice == 5)
    {
        mealCost = regularMeal;
        destination = "St. Louis";
        System.out.print("Would you like to drive or fly? ");
        String transportation = keyboard.next();
        if (transportation.equalsIgnoreCase("drive"))
        {
            miles = 551.00;
            airfare = 0;
        }
        else if (transportation.equalsIgnoreCase("fly"))
        {
            miles = 0;
            airfare = 290.00;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid selection");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid destination");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("These are the hotels with vacancies:");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%.0f\n", "1. Budgetel", "$", budgetel);
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%.0f\n", "2. Holiday Inn", "$", holidayInn);
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%.0f\n", "3. Sheraton", "$", sheraton);
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%.0f\n", "4. Hyatt", "$", hyatt);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Which hotel would you like to stay at? ");
    int hotelChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (hotelChoice == 1)
    {
        hotelCost = budgetel;
        hotel = "Budgetel";
    }
    else if (hotelChoice == 2)
    {
        hotelCost = holidayInn;
        hotel = "Holiday Inn";
    }
    else if (hotelChoice == 3)
    {
        hotelCost = sheraton;
        hotel = "Sheraton";
    }
    else if (hotelChoice == 4)
    {
        hotelCost = hyatt;
        hotel = "Hyatt";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid selection");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Cost for your trip (drive to " + destination + ", staying at " + hotel + " for " + days + " days):");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s%1s%3s%3.2f\n", "Transportation", ":", "$", miles/gasPrice);
}
}
```

down at the bottom where i go to print out the destination and hotel, it is saying that the local variables aren't initialized. How can I get my code so that the values assigned to these variables in my if statements carries over to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise your variables. For example, change

```
String destination;
```

to

```
String destination = null;
```

and the same for all the other variables that are not initialised.

Comment: thank you so much! seems like an important caveat that our instructor should have mentioned lol

Comment: Consider yourself lucky that you're using Java where the compiler points out this programming error; if you were using C++ for example, you wouldn't notice until your program starts crashing for mysterious reasons!

Comment: yeah thank god for eclipse. cant say how many times i have made a stupid syntax error and eclipse says "hey, don't do that"

Comment: sorry about not marking correct initially, I am not familiar with this site. I rectified that for you!

Answer (score 0):

if your String variable is not initialized will be a null value, so you need to initialize it's value, then when the variable goes through your if statements will get the right value for the result, you can declare String hotel=""; for example. hope to help